# how to uncheck exclude image checkbox at mass image import

Tags: import, image-upload

I am trying to update the images of my catalog with the following CSV:

```
sku,image,small_image,thumbnail
aaaaaa,/TP1501054_15_1.jpg,/TP1501054_15_1.jpg,/TP1501054_15_1.jpg
```

I like to know how i can exclude the small_image and thubmnail. I am using default magento enterprise import for importing. I dont like to use MAGMI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question completely, you can add a column `_media_is_disabled` and fill it with `1` to disable the according images.
A full description of how image import works can be found at https://www.integer-net.com/importing-products-with-the-import-export-interface/.

Comment: When I do this I get "image not found" becuase I am not trying to import images for the first time.  Is there a way to change an image that is already in there?